# Where does R store data

Tags: r

I am new to r language. I am not sure if I modify the data (e.g. by adding a column), will the dataset itself be changed forever? I am afraid of changing the raw dataset so every time I do some analysis I tend to assign the data to another name. But I just want to know if this is even necessary.

Comment: I'm assuming you're reading the data from an external source, such as a csv file. Data in R is stored in memory. You're not changing the file, but there are ways you can write back to the file. These are almost always explicitly done through functions designed to write from R back to the data source. Stuff you do to data frames within R are purely in R.

Comment: When you read a file with `read...` or `load`, the data is put in memory (your environment). If you make changes, the original file is not modified unless you use `write...` or `save` with the same file name. When you close R, you are asked if you want to "save your workspace". If you click "Save" all of the objects in your current environment are saved in a file called ".RData". If you want to save your modifications, it is better to do it deliberately than to depend on this latter method.

Comment: someone should post an answer (rather than answering in comments) ...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above, R does not automatically change the data on disk.  To change the data on disk, you have to explicitly write the data back out to the same file you got it from.  R functions work in memory.  So you don't have to worry about messing up the original dataset.

Also note that it doesn't hurt anything to assign your dataset a new name when returning from some manipulation function.  Sometimes it is helpful to do this for debugging purposes.

Perhaps you are thinking this way because you have worked with SAS.  In SAS, everything you do is immediately written to disk.  R is totally different.